# Is it possible to calculate data member different constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, calculator, stp

I'm doing an assignment on creating an STP - A Payroll Management System for a company. I was given 11 classes (Employee, Employees, Employer, Employers, STP, STPLog, Report, In, Session, Utils)
I just finished initializing data members in **Employee** and **Employers** but in STP, there are members which require calculation from the members in Employee. For example:
totalWages = sum of 'income' in **Employee**.
Im just wondering if it's possible to do that calculation in **STP** constructor? And the way to do so? Because I can do that in **Employee** with its data members.
Here's my code:

```
//STP.java//
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class STP {
    private double totalWages;
        
public STP (double totalWages){
   this.totalWages = totalWages; 
>                    ---------^ part need to calculate 
  }


}
//Employee.java//
public class Employee {
    
    private int hours;
    private double payPerHour;
    private double income;
    

    public Employee (int hours, double payPerHour) {
        
        this.hours = hours;
        this.payPerHour = payPerHour;
        this.income = hours*payPerHour*52;
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: It seems like you want many employees but you have not defined an array.  Once you have an array you will need a `for` loop inside the STP constructor to what you want.

Comment: Yes, you can do a calculation in a constructor. I assume that `Employees` contains a list of `Employee`. I also guess that you need to iterate through the list, get the `income` for each `Employee` and add them together. If you [edit] your question and post a [mcve] then I may be able to show you the relevant code.

Comment: @Abra Hi I have edited to the one i need, I'm new to all this so i don't know if that's correct, my apologise if so.

Comment: I see that you are having trouble posting a [mcve]. What is not clear? Post the minimal amount of code that I can copy and compile and run. Just indicate which part (of the code in your minimal, reproducible example) you need help with.